# Why am I getting FALSE returned?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I keeping getting FALSE in the target cell.  I feel like I have tried everything but can't seem to find the error.

```
  =IF(AND(K2<=2014,G2<=36),
     IF(AND(K2<=2015,G2>=48),
       IF(AND(K2>=2016,G2>=60),
         IF(AND(K2<=2017,G2>=72),
           IF(AND(K2<=2018,K2>=2020,G2>=84),
             IF(AND(K2<=2021,K2>=2023,G2>=96),
               IF(D2<7500,"-D",IF(D2<20000,"-l",
                 IF(D2<30000,"-k",IF(D2<40000,"-j",
                   IF(D2<50000,D2*0.0025,
                     IF(D2>=50000,D2*0.0025)))))))))))
```

the IF/AND statements are 'model year' (K2) and 'loan term' (G2), if the statement returns TRUE then it moves to the regular IF and calculates the amount of bonus (D2).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide some sample data.

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: 1) the first If when true,  goes to the second if which cannont be true, 2) I don't see in the nesting where the false conditions are handled

Comment: Does each IF AND need it's own false condition?

Comment: 1) I suggest that you look at the function with the aid of a "pretty printer" such as [Excel Formula Beautifier](https://www.excelformulabeautifier.com/). 2) Please note that *if x<1 and x>2* is *always* false because x cannot be both less than 1 and more than 2 at the same time.

Comment: Maybe show us sample data and expected outcome. `IF(D2<7500,"-D",IF(D2<20000,"-l",IF(D2<30000,"-k",IF(D2<40000,"-j",IF(D2<50000,D20.0025,IF(D2>=50000,D20.0025))))))` could probably be replaced with a lookup table

Comment: @Gavin, when Excel encounters a false condition it will perform the action "else" action. If  the action is not specified the result will be defaulted to `FALSE`. So if no action is specified it makes it difficult to troubleshoot which of the 10 `ifs` is causing you problems

Comment: why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve so we can assist further.  For example you have `IF(D2<50000,D2*0.0025,IF(D2>=50000,D2*0.0025)` which is a complicated way to say `D2*0.0025`

Comment: "Does each IF AND need it's own false condition?" - Yes

Comment: Are there a few conditions missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have no success path.

Once the code is laid out in a more readable manner it becomes clear that once any of your IF conditions become TRUE instead of providing a success path, you provide another test that will return FALSE.

##### Explanation

- Your first test is `IF(AND(K2<=2014,G2<=36),value_if_true)`
- if the test is FALSE, you haven't provided another value so FALSE;
- if the test is TRUE, the value_if_true is `IF(AND(K2<=2015,G2>=48),value_if_true)`
- again, if this next test is FALSE, you haven't provided another value so FALSE;
- this last test would necessarily be FALSE since `AND(G2<=36,G2>=48)=FALSE`,

So, if your first conditional test is FALSE, the outcome is FALSE.  If it happens to be TRUE, the outcome of the second conditional is always FALSE.

Comment: i was trying to put the FALSE in the last part of the statement but it's not working ......IF(D2>=50000,D2*0.0025)))))))))),"-")...the ,"-" being the FALSE statement

Comment: i'm looking to return a reserve $ amount based of the amount financed (D2) eg IF(D2<12500,D2*0.012) but constrict it to vehicle model (K2) and max finance term (G2) eg model year K2 2012-2014 = max term 36, 2015 = max term 48, 2016-2017 = max term 72

Comment: IF term between 2012-2014, AND<= 36mths = finance amt * % reserve, FALSE = "-", IF term < 2015, AND<= 48mths = finance amt * % reserve, FALSE = "-", IF term between 2016-2017, AND<= 72mths = finance amt * % reserve, FALSE = "-" –

Comment: but for example if model  yr <2014 but term is >36 i need result to be "-"

Comment: `IF <2014 AND >36, THEN "-", ELSE IF <2017, AND <=72mos  THEN finance amt * % reserve, ELSE "-" `